# How to control undefined state on kendo checkbox

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, kendo-ui, treeview

I programatically change the state of a kendo treeview checkbox by this code:

```
$(node).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked", !currentItem.checked);
           currentItem.checked = !currentItem.checked;
```

This code is a rollback code.
The UI result for this is this:
[image]

The parent is in the undefined state even the child are not in true state.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the [`updateIndeterminate`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/treeview/methods/updateindeterminate) method of your treeview after changing the state of your checkbox.

The documentation provides this example:

```
<div id="treeview"></div>
<script>
$("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
  checkboxes: {
    checkChildren: true
  },
  dataSource: [
    { text: "foo", expanded: true, items: [
      { text: "bar" },
      { text: "baz" },
      { text: "qux" }
    ] }
  ]
});

$(":checkbox").filter(function() {
  var text = $(this).parent().next().text();
  return text != "bar" && text != "foo";
}).prop("checked", true);

var treeview = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView");
treeview.updateIndeterminate();
</script>
```